# Set environment variable in .htaccess when the URL starts with directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set an environment variable in my .htaccess based on the 1st subdirectory of a URL. As long as the URL contains **dira** as the 1st subdirectory, it should set my variable (myvar) to a value of 123. For example, these URLs should work:

```
test.com/dira
test.com/dira/
test.com/dira/b
test.com/dira/b/
test.com/dira/b/random.html
test.com/dira/b/2
test.com/dira/b/2/
test.com/dira/b/2/and-so-in-into-infinity
```

Any other URL should be ignored, like these:

```
test.com
test.com/
test.com/dirb
test.com/dirc/123/456/789/blah
test.com/123/dira/
test.com/dirz/
```

I've tried all these rules in my .htaccess without success:

```
RewriteRule ^dira(.*)$ [E=myvar:123]
RewriteRule ^dira/(.*)$ [E=myvar:123]
RewriteRule ^dira/? [E=myvar:123]
RewriteRule ^dira/?$ [E=myvar:123]
```

In every case, **myvar** isn't set. So my question is, what's the syntax to wildcard everything after the first sub-directory? Thanks.

Comment: What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Is `REDIRECT_myvar` set?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?acid={ENV:myvar} [L]` 
I also access it in PHP via `$_SERVER['myvar'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^dira(.*)$ [E=myvar:123]
> RewriteRule ^dira/(.*)$ [E=myvar:123]
> RewriteRule ^dira/? [E=myvar:123]
> RewriteRule ^dira/?$ [E=myvar:123]
> ```

You are missing the *substitution* string (2nd argument) so none of these directives are actually setting an environment variable. `[E=myvar:123]` is seen as the *substitution* string (2nd argument), so would result in a rather malformed internal rewrite.

It should read something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^dira($|/) - [E=myvar:123]
```

Note the single hyphen (`-`) as the substitution string (2nd argument) indicating "no substitution".

The regex `^dira($|/)` matches any URL-path that contains `dira` as the first *complete* path segment. eg. It matches `dira`, `dira/` and `dira/anything`, but not `dirasomething`.

However, there are additional "problems" resulting from other directives in your `.htaccess` file...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?acid={ENV:myvar} [L]
> ```

(*Aside:* That should be `%{ENV:myvar}` - you are missing the `%` prefix.)

If that is the only other rule you have in your `.htaccess` file then the `myvar` env var should now be successfully set when requesting `/dira/something`, but not `/dira` or `/dira/`. (Because both `/dira` and `/dira/` are internally rewritten by the above rule.)

The reason being, when matched, the above `RewriteRule` triggers a second pass of the rewrite engine (when used in `.htaccess`). This second pass causes any environment variables that are already set to be renamed with a `REDIRECT_` prefix. ie. `myvar` becomes `REDIRECT_myvar`. `myvar` is not (re)set on the second pass because `index.php` does not match your rule.

You can either:

- Modify the above `RewriteRule` directive (that internally rewrites the request) to prevent a second pass of the rewrite engine. This can be done by changing the `L` flag to `END` (requires Apache 2.4). For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?acid=%{ENV:myvar} [END]
  ```

  Note that I corrected the env var reference by including the `%` prefix. And there is no need to backslash-escape literal dots when used inside a regex character class.

  However, you will need to be mindful of future rules you add in order to prevent loops by the rewrite engine. And sometimes the looping nature of the rewrite engine can be desirable.

**OR**

- Check for both `myvar` *and* `REDIRECT_myvar` in your PHP code (ie. `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_myvar']`). Since not all requests that start `dira` are rewritten by the above rule, you'll have either `myvar` or `REDIRECT_myvar` set at different times. Specifically, `/dira` and `/dira/` will result in `REDIRECT_myvar` being set and `/dira/something` will have the expected `myvar` set (since it's not rewritten).